# How to connect to a remote csv file with duckdb or arrow in R?

Tags: r, apache-arrow, dbplyr, duckdb

### Goal

Connect to a large remote csv file to query a subset of the data.

[This page](https://datahub.transportation.gov/Automobiles/Next-Generation-Simulation-NGSIM-Vehicle-Trajector/8ect-6jqj) has a button to download a csv file. If I copy the link and run the following, the data is loaded into memory:

```
foo <- data.table::fread("https://datahub.transportation.gov/api/views/8ect-6jqj/rows.csv?date=20231118&accessType=DOWNLOAD")
```

### Trying duckdb via dbplyr:

```
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
library(duckdb)

(con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), 
                  dbdir = ":memory:",
                  "https://datahub.transportation.gov/api/views/8ect-6jqj/rows.csv?date=20231118&accessType=DOWNLOAD"))
# <duckdb_connection f96e0 driver=<duckdb_driver fd1f0 dbdir=':memory:' read_only=FALSE bigint=numeric>>
```

But this results in:

```
> dbListTables(con)
character(0)
```

### Trying arrow:

```
 > open_dataset(sources = "https://datahub.transportation.gov/api/views/8ect-6jqj/rows.csv?date=20231118&accessType=DOWNLOAD")
Error: Invalid: Unrecognized filesystem type in URI: https://datahub.transportation.gov/api/views/8ect-6jqj/rows.csv?date=20231118&accessType=DOWNLOAD
```

Is this because of some kind of restriction by the provider or am I using the packages wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No tool that I'm aware of is going to give you lazy/efficient access to the data when stored on a remote HTTP(s) server as CSV.

If you want lazy access (with that file, which is quite big), then you still need to download it, and then you have several options. Two of them:

1. `arrow::read_csv_arrow("path/to/file.csv", as_data_frame=FALSE)` which provides you a `dplyr`-friendly connection that allows "lazy" filtering and mutate/summarize and several other techniques.

   Because of how it operates, it only pulls into memory data that passes all of your filters. This means that if you follow this immediately with `%>% collect()` (it relies on `dplyr` and either base `` `|>` `` or `` magrittr::`%>%` `` for its functionality), then it will load the entire CSV into R's memory, which seems not what you want.
2. With `duckdb_read_csv(con, "some_table", files="path/to/file.csv")`, which will create (or add-to) a table in a table in an existing duckdb database.

   Note: if you are using `":memory:"`, then this will clearly load the entire CSV file into RAM of the system, though with the small distinction that it is stored with duckdb's methodology, not R's. This might be helpful or no difference, I have not checked.

   If you go this route, I recommend you use an on-disk duckdb file so that you don't load the entire file into memory. If you're familiar with SQL, this may be preferred.

They both have their advantages. If you are already familiar with SQL and want to capitalize on that, then perhaps the duckdb route is preferred. If you're already familiar with `dplyr`, then perhaps the `arrow` "lazy" fashion is good. If neither SQL nor dplyr are already in your personal toolkit of proficiency, then in general I think many would recommend dplyr-based tools, but I think you would do well to take inventory of your future demands, hopes, and expectations to see if SQL will be coming your way anyway. (Yes, there's also `dbplyr` which helps mask this SQL thing ... again, subjective. Over to you.)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the csv and used `arrow` that worked quite well.

Comment: Nice answer. I think `dbplyr` may be the best way to interact with DuckDB. I find calling DuckDB's `read_csv_auto()` beats `duckdb_read_csv()`, which seems to use elements of `read.csv()` to parse files: `tbl(con, "read_csv_auto('path/to/file.csv')")`

Some notes: (1) `duckdb_read_csv` doesn't appear to read everything into RAM. (2) `read_csv_arrow` seems to work fine with `|>`.

Comment: @IanGow (1) There's a nuance to "read everything into RAM": if the duck database is `":memory:"`, then _all of it_ is completely within RAM, so anything you read from external files will also be in RAM as well. Granted, it is not loaded into R's resident memory (for better or worse), but it is most certainly in RAM. (2) Thanks, I revised the wording to better reflect the intent.

Comment: @r2evans It *seems* that DuckDB has some ability to read lazily even with `":memory:"`. For example, reading a 3.4GB parquet file I have doesn't appear to use up any RAM anywhere. (That said, this may not apply equally to CSV files.) But if I `compute()` a subset of that data, RAM usage goes up dramatically. It does seem that the memory usage is within the R process, which is nice (one can see the RAM usage within RStudio).

Comment: @r2evans It *seems* there is some laziness with CSVs too, but it's limited. While, `rows |> filter(Vehicle_ID == 2224)` seems to have limited effect on memory,  `rows |>  count(Vehicle_ID)` appears to trigger a full read into memory. Memory usage with a parquet version is much better in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmarks based on the answer from @r2evans. If you convert to parquet (a format that works well with either `arrow` or DuckDB), subsequent steps become much faster.

Also RAM consumption is high for all options except the very last one. (Surprisingly it's worst for `arrow::read_csv_arrow()`.) (To test memory consumption, I started a new R session before running just the commands needed to do `df |> count(Vehicle_ID) |> arrange(Vehicle_ID) |> collect()`.)

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
t <- "rows.csv" # tempfile()

options(timeout = max(2000, getOption("timeout")))
url <- paste0("https://datahub.transportation.gov/api/views/",
              "8ect-6jqj/rows.csv?date=20231118&accessType=DOWNLOAD")
# download.file(url, t)

start <- Sys.time()
duckdb::duckdb_read_csv(db, name = "rows", t)
df <- tbl(db, "rows")
df |> count(Vehicle_ID)
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 2]
#> # Database: DuckDB v0.9.1 [root@Darwin 23.2.0:R 4.3.2/:memory:]
#>    Vehicle_ID     n
#>         <int> <dbl>
#>  1          1  1874
#>  2          2  4878
#>  3          3  2600
#>  4          4  3974
#>  5          5  5457
#>  6          6  2816
#>  7          7  2527
#>  8          8  2942
#>  9          9  4727
#> 10         10  4818
#> # ℹ more rows
Sys.time() - start
#> Time difference of 4.800587 secs

start <- Sys.time()
df <- arrow::read_csv_arrow(t, as_data_frame=FALSE)
df |> count(Vehicle_ID) |> arrange(Vehicle_ID) |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 3,233 × 2
#>    Vehicle_ID     n
#>         <int> <int>
#>  1          1  1874
#>  2          2  4878
#>  3          3  2600
#>  4          4  3974
#>  5          5  5457
#>  6          6  2816
#>  7          7  2527
#>  8          8  2942
#>  9          9  4727
#> 10         10  4818
#> # ℹ 3,223 more rows
Sys.time() - start
#> Time difference of 2.065795 secs


start <- Sys.time()
df_sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM read_csv_auto('", t, "')")
df <- tbl(db, sql(df_sql))
df |> count(Vehicle_ID) |> arrange(Vehicle_ID) |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 3,233 × 2
#>    Vehicle_ID     n
#>         <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1          1  1874
#>  2          2  4878
#>  3          3  2600
#>  4          4  3974
#>  5          5  5457
#>  6          6  2816
#>  7          7  2527
#>  8          8  2942
#>  9          9  4727
#> 10         10  4818
#> # ℹ 3,223 more rows
Sys.time() - start
#> Time difference of 2.119 secs

start <- Sys.time()
pq_sql <- paste0("COPY (FROM read_csv_auto('", t, "')) TO 'rows.parquet'")
dbExecute(db, pq_sql)
#> [1] 11850526
Sys.time() - start
#> Time difference of 4.548899 secs

start <- Sys.time()
df_sql <- paste0("SELECT * FROM 'rows.parquet'")
df <- tbl(db, sql(df_sql))
df |> count(Vehicle_ID) |> arrange(Vehicle_ID) |> collect()
#> # A tibble: 3,233 × 2
#>    Vehicle_ID     n
#>         <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1          1  1874
#>  2          2  4878
#>  3          3  2600
#>  4          4  3974
#>  5          5  5457
#>  6          6  2816
#>  7          7  2527
#>  8          8  2942
#>  9          9  4727
#> 10         10  4818
#> # ℹ 3,223 more rows
Sys.time() - start
#> Time difference of 0.07211113 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Cool! These options seem to be much quicker than downloading the CSV first. Or may be it is your internet speed.

Comment: Unfortunately these options all *start with* a downloaded CSV (`download.file(url, t)`).

Comment: @IanGow, thanks for compiling the benchmarking. I suggest the use of `bench::mark(..)` or `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(..)` for comparing different expressions, as a single-run can easily be hindered by things extrinsic to the expression itself (such as garbage-collection) or extrinsic to R (OS-level stuff).